# use model attribute from spring controller in ng-show

Tags: html, angularjs, spring

Using spring boot,angualrjs with html as view
I am using this in index.html

```
<a ng-show="permission=='write'">
```

from spring boot controller I am returning permission in model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  String getIndex(Model model)
{
   model.addAttribute("permission","write");
   return "index";

}
```

tab with  tag is not visible in view.while console has no error.
How do I use model attribute value in ng-show?

Comment: what is the value you are getting?

Comment: What server side view technology are you using?

Comment: I am getting same ng-show="permission=='write'", instead of true or false.I am using thymeleaf,spring boot with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, while checking equals condition it should be ===

change your ng-show as `<a ng-show="permission==='write'">`

Also there is a similar post, have a look on this [how to get model attribute value in angularjs from spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929602/how-to-get-model-attribute-value-in-angularjs-from-spring-controller)

Comment: === did not work,I had a look on this post but given answers did not work for me

Comment: can you post more details on the issue such as what is the output on the screen and on the console

Comment: I am not able to view the tab containing tag <a> ,console has no error

Comment: == is enough in ng-show ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998886/angularjs-is-complaining-about-an-unexpected-token-in-an-expression-when-i-try